# On describing percentiles within quartiles

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, percentile, quantile

In describing the relationship between percentiles and quartiles of a data set, is it accurate to say that the *percentiles belonging to the first quartile* range from the zeroth to the 24th percentile?

As such, the value at the 25th percentile marks the boundary of the first quartile; it belongs to the second quartile.

Visually, this could be represented as:

Q1  |  Q2  |  Q3  | Q4

0-24 | 25-49 | 50-74 | 75-99

Comment: Thoughtful question: 25th percentile and first quartile are the same thing. Also median and 50th percentile are the same. OK to say 10th quartile is within the lower quarter of the data and to say 10th percentile < 25th percentile, but I'm not sure about 10th percentile 'belongs to' 
 (or 'belongs in') 25th quartile. (Never seen 'belongs' used in that way; 25th percentile is a _value,_ not an _interval._)